# Can't import .dae files to Xcode

Tags: xcode, scenekit, arkit

I cannot import any .dae files to my Xcode because it crashes instantly. In fact, I cannot even open .dae files on my mac. I have Xcode 9.2 Beta. I would like to edit the files in Xcode automatically from .dae to .scn and use it to build and ARKit app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627965/how-to-convert-dae-to-scn-files-in-scenekit

Comment: no, the link is useless since I cannot relate to that problem. I can't even select the .dae files, not to mention open them